# why my code is showing syntax error in line cost_of_green =cost_of_green + X*G

Tags: python

Help me to find the reason of error in my code cost_of_green =cost_of_green + X*G

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(0,T):
    cost_of_green = 0
    cost_of_purple =0

    G = int(input())
    P = int(input())

    n = int(input())
    for j in range(0,n):
        X = int(input())
        Y = int(input()

        cost_of_green =cost_of_green + X*G
        cost_of_purple = cost_of_purple + Y*P

    print(cost_of_green+cost_of_purple)
```

Comment: Hint: Syntax errors are often caused by something above the place mentioned by compiler/interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ')' at the `Y = int(input()`. You should write `Y = int(input())` to make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple syntax error `Y = int(input()`
.
`)` at end of line is missing.
This is causing the complier to throw an error for the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the end parenthesis for the line

```
Y = int(input())
```

Which causes the compiler to have the wrong context for the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ) at the end where you are taking in the value of Y. 
Y=int(input())
It will work post that.